# Change of order of limit and function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a open and bounded domain. Suppose that $f(x)$ is a $C^1$ function for $x\in\Omega$ and $\{ x_k \}_{k=1}^{k=\infty}\in\Omega$ is a sequence with $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} x_k=x_0$. Then is $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} f(x_k)=f(x_0)$ true?

Comment: The continuity of $f$ in $x_0$ gives you that.

Comment: So $f$ being $C^0$ is enough to guarantee the desired result, right?

Comment: Yes. If you are interested in only particular $x_0$, even less suffices, but if you're interested in all $x_0 \in \Omega$, continuity of $f$ is precisely what you need.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The equality $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} f(x_k)=f(x_0)\tag{1}$$ holds for every continuous $(C^0)$ function on $\Omega$, *provided that* $x_0\in \Omega$. (This assumption was not explicitly stated.) In general,   a sequence in $\Omega$ may converge to a point $x_0\in \partial \Omega$. Then the existence of the limit $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} f(x_k)$ is not as easy to establish, and the derivative of $f$ may actually help. For example, if $\partial \Omega$ is smooth (more  generally, Lipschitz) and the gradient $\nabla  f$ is bounded, one can show (using mean value theorem) that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in $\Omega$. Lipschitz continuity implies that $f$ extends to a  continuous function on $\overline{\Omega}$, and then (1) is valid for all $x_0\in\overline{\Omega}$.